# if m,n are positive integers such that; $3m+n=3 lcm(m,n)+gcd(m,n)$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> if m,n are positive integers such that; $3m+n=3 lcm(m,n)+gcd(m,n)$ prove that $n|m$

---

if $m=nk$ the result follows directly as $\gcd(m,n)=n$ and $lcm(m,n)=m$.

let $\gcd(m,n)=d$ then
$$3m+n=\frac{mn}{d}+d$$

But i dont see any thing helpful from here.

Also i think the following inequalities may be helpful :

$\gcd(m,n)\le \min(m,n)$
and

$lcm(m,n)|\le mn$

Comment: As [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3658798/242) we can reduce to the case $\,m,n\,$ coprime where it becomes $\ 3m+n = 3mn+1,\,$ which becomes $\ (3m-1)(n-1)= 0\ $ by [completing the product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242), with obvious solutions.

Comment: @BillDubuque thank you for the reference but i personally don't think this is a duplicate.Agreed the combination of sources you mention   help,but again i think this is far from a duplicate

Comment: As I explained above, it follows *immediately* by applying the general method I describe in the first link, then completing the product. There is nothing at all novel in this instance. We already have *many* problems like this.

Comment: @BillDubuque sorry ,i didn't know there were so many similar problems.I merely mentioned it as i have never seen questions being flagged duplicate in this fashion maybe because i am not as expereinced as you with this site. Thank you for mentioning this.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions) for more on abstract dupes. In short: in order for the site to flourish as a Q&A site it is necessary to stop if from being flooded with hundreds of minor variation of problems, e.g. homework questions, because that greatly complicates searching for the best answers - which is one of the primary purposes of  the site. Generally it is best to delete dupes which add nothing novel, but "gamification" often gets in the way of that.

Comment: @BillDubuque so should i delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $d=\gcd(m,n)$. Let $m=dk,n=dl$, then dividing both sides of the equation $3m+n=3\cdot\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)+\gcd(m,n)$ by $d$ we get
$$3k+l=3kl+1\iff (3k-1)(l-1)=0$$
which is true if either $k=\frac13$ or $l=1$. Now $k$ is an integer and cannoot be $\frac13$. So we must have $l=1$, or that $n=d$.